# Word frequency per pandas dataframe row

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out how to get most frequent words per dataframe row - lets say the top 10 most frequent words.  I have code that gets me most frequent words for the whole DF, but now I need to be more granular.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:/temp/comments.csv',encoding='latin-1',names=['client','comments'])
df1.head(3)
```

[image]

Now I can get the most frequent words on the whole df1:

```
y = pd.Series(' '.join(df1['description']).lower().split()).value_counts()[:10]
```

how to get that info per df row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different ways you can do this, depending on whether you want a dataframe, series of dictionaries, or list of dictionaries.

```
from collections import Counter

# dataframe of word counts per row
res = df['comments'].str.split().apply(pd.value_counts)

# series of dictionaries of word counts, each series entry covering one row
res = df['comments'].str.split().apply(Counter)

# list of dictionaries of word counts, each list item covering one row
res = [Counter(x) for x in df['comments'].str.split()]
```